# Adding multiple versions of a project into SVN and tagging them

Tags: svn, tags, repository, trunk

I'm fairly new to the SVN thing, but am getting to grips with it. Basically I have a project already created in Eclipse, we have versions 2.1, 2.2 & 2.3 of the project saved locally on the computer. I have set up my server repository  for the first (2.1) so it's in the trunk folder, and has a tagged version (tag 2.1), but how can i go about adding 2.2 & 2.3, so they; can be added to the tag folder, and then we can use 2.3 as the trunk version:

Our repository structure looks like this just to give you guys a visual as my explanation is not the clearest:

```
RepositoryLocation/

CoreFiles/
trunk
tags

CoreWeb/
trunk
tags

etcFolders/
trunk
tags
```

(There are about 9 different folders within each project)

We're pretty sure we would like a trunk / tag for each folder within the project, after doing some research we think this would make changing certain areas in the future easier. However we are unsure how to now add 2.2, then 2.3 projects and all the associated folders into the tags, the folder structures within the projects are exactly the same so can't imagine it to be too difficult with the right knowledge. Any comments welcomed, and apologies if this wasn't the clearest when describing this.

Answer (score 2):

If the project had been in SVN from the start, you would have the following:

```
trunk ------------------------------------------------------------------->
         \_ v2.1 tag             \_v2.2 tag          \_v2.3 tag
```

where each `-` represents a new commit in trunk.

If you want to sort of recreate this history, then start from the trunk you have, containing the code as it was in v2.1. Then, in your working copy, replace all the files by the files from version 2.2, commit, then tag. Then replace all the files by the files from version 2.3, commit, then tag.

That's assuming you're using the latest version of SVN, which only has one .svn folder at the root. Don't delete this folder when replaing old files by newer ones.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, sorry about the delayed response but it now works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up to @JB:

If *only* `CoreFiles + CoreWeb + etcFolders` forms project, you'll better to have single trunk/branches/tags tree in the root of repo (thus - copy the whole project)

If  CoreFiles **and** CoreWeb **and** etcFolders are independent projects, but theirs combination as *subprojects* produces *superproject*, you can have current tree (but you forgot `/branches` in every base-project), but also create "combined superproject" with externals (in the root of this repo or /better/ in new separate repository)